# Hide custom JavaScript button on certain conditions

Tags: apex

I want to hide a custom button from a detail page based on some condition. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try moving to a formula "button"?

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. Earlier we could have used JS to control button visiblity via sidebar components. But Salesforce has stopped supporting this hack 5-6 releases back.

The possible ways are:

1. Create different page layouts and link them to different record types. Change record types based on your conditions.
2. Create a custom page.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can't hide a button if it has been added to standard page layout, As an alternative option you can write your logic on button click and show error message to the user.

For example if you have a button which will render only if Opportunity stage is Closed Won. You can write logic on button click and alert it as

> Opportunity should be closed won

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered a benefit which custom actions using a `Visualforce Page` enjoy over putting your logic into `Javascript`, namely with the former you can do a [formula button](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004375). You could then do something like:

```
IF(myCondition,
    HYPERLINK('/apex/MyPage?Id=' & Id, IMAGE(image_url, 'Take Action')),
    'Cannot Take Action'
)
```

You might be able to shoehorn some `Javascript` into a formula to make something similar work. I would think it's easier to just make the logic controller/extension driven.